# Apache2 is serving "download" document instead of website

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, cacti

I updated my Ubuntu server this morning from 20.04 to 22.04. Apache2, PHP, Mysql all got updated in the process. I have Cacti installed on this server to monitor a few of our switches and firewall. After the OS update, when I try to visit the Cacti site, Edge, Safari, Firefox, etc etc, all try to download a file called.. "download". It the index.php of the cacti directory.

Thinking PHP wasn't installed, I set up a test.php with the phpinfo(), and it serves it fine.

I'am not the best at Apache2 configs, but I've been digging all day to get my Cacti server back up and running.

PHP went from 7.4 -> 8.1

I did update the cacti install, thinking that could have been the issue, but its the same problem.

Looking for some help before I just blow this server away and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably one of these commands

```
sudo apt install apache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have already ran those commands. I re-ran them just for giggles, and it started working. Thanks Jasen!